# How do I return a single row as well as multple entries using group_concat in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I hope this one is a relatively easy one to solve, but here is the problem I'm faced with:

SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    job.job_id
    ,job_reference
    ,job_title
    ,jc.name as job_category_name
    ,ps.name as position_status_name
    ,group_concat(pt.name ORDER BY pt.position_type_id SEPARATOR ' / ') as position_type_name
    ,cty.name as city_name
    ,min.amount as min_salary
    ,max.amount as max_salary
    ,job_description
    ,skills_required
    ,additional_notes
FROM job
INNER JOIN job_category jc ON job.job_category_id = jc.job_category_id
INNER JOIN position_status ps ON job.position_status_id = ps.position_status_id
INNER JOIN job_position_type jpt ON job.job_id = jpt.job_id
INNER JOIN position_type pt ON jpt.position_type_id = pt.position_type_id
INNER JOIN city cty ON job.city_id = cty.city_id
INNER JOIN salary min ON job.min_salary_id = min.salary_id
INNER JOIN salary max ON job.max_salary_id = max.salary_id;
```

The query is only returning the entries where job_position_type table has multiple entries and not if job_position_type only has a single entry.

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what you concretely want to do?

Comment: @Adrien Brunelat thanks for your comment but it seems like all I had to do was add a GROUP BY clause to the end of my SQL statement.

Comment: Then you should consider either posting that as an answer or delete your post.

Comment: @Adrien Brunelat yeah going to post a detailed answer to the question a bit later on.  Thanks for keeping me on my toes Lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I managed to sort out my problem pretty easily actually, here is my original SQL as specified above:

```
SELECT
    job.job_id
    ,job_reference
    ,job_title
    ,jc.name as job_category_name
    ,ps.name as position_status_name
    ,group_concat(pt.name ORDER BY pt.position_type_id SEPARATOR ' / ') as position_type_name
    ,cty.name as city_name
    ,min.amount as min_salary
    ,max.amount as max_salary
    ,job_description
    ,skills_required
    ,additional_notes
FROM job
INNER JOIN job_category jc ON job.job_category_id = jc.job_category_id
INNER JOIN position_status ps ON job.position_status_id = ps.position_status_id
INNER JOIN job_position_type jpt ON job.job_id = jpt.job_id
INNER JOIN position_type pt ON jpt.position_type_id = pt.position_type_id
INNER JOIN city cty ON job.city_id = cty.city_id
INNER JOIN salary min ON job.min_salary_id = min.salary_id
INNER JOIN salary max ON job.max_salary_id = max.salary_id;
```

And this is what the query returns:

[image: Position type name displaying all concatenated rows]

And the solution was just to add a group by clause so that it seperates the rows, here is my update SQL:

```
SELECT
    job.job_id
    ,job_reference
    ,job_title
    ,jc.name as job_category_name
    ,ps.name as position_status_name
    ,group_concat(pt.name ORDER BY pt.position_type_id SEPARATOR ' / ') as position_type_name
    ,cty.name as city_name
    ,min.amount as min_salary
    ,max.amount as max_salary
    ,job_description
    ,skills_required
    ,additional_notes
FROM job
INNER JOIN job_category jc ON job.job_category_id = jc.job_category_id
INNER JOIN position_status ps ON job.position_status_id = ps.position_status_id
INNER JOIN job_position_type jpt ON job.job_id = jpt.job_id
INNER JOIN position_type pt ON jpt.position_type_id = pt.position_type_id
INNER JOIN city cty ON job.city_id = cty.city_id
INNER JOIN salary min ON job.min_salary_id = min.salary_id
INNER JOIN salary max ON job.max_salary_id = max.salary_id
GROUP BY pt.position_type_id;
```

And here is the expected result I wanted:

[image: Position type id grouped by position type id]

Thanks once again to @Adrien Brunelat for taking a look at my question.